# When i am running my application i got error Compilation Error?

Tags: asp.net

When I am running my application, I am getting this erro like this:

> The type or namespace name 'Script' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SlideService : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

can u help me ?

Comment: Are you compiling your app for .Net 3.5? AFAIK the ScriptService attribute is only available from 3.5 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the project this file is in has a reference to the `System.Web` assembly.

In the Solution Explorer, open the project, right click on the References node and select `Add Reference` - select the .NET tab and choose the `System.Web` assembly in order to add it.

If the project already has this reference, you need to ensure that your source file has access to the types defined in it - you do this with a `using` declaration - add it to the top of your file (assuming C#):

```
using System.Web;
```

Comment: @Oded I added the reference what u say even though it is not working it is giving same error

Comment: @Surya sasidhar - have you added the `using` statement?

Comment: @Surya sasidhar - Have you looked at where `Script` comes from? Make sure you also have a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` in your project.

Comment: @Surya sasidhar - And you are getting the same error? Can you post the line where the compiler is complaining about?

Comment: Now I am getting                     The type 'System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptServiceAttribute' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\1.0.61025.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll' and 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'

Comment: @Surya sasidhar - Make sure you have only _one_ reference for each DLL in the references list.

Comment: How can remove the dll and which one i have to remove @Oded

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you might be missing an assembly reference here. According to [the documentation of the System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptServiceAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx), it's located in `System.Web.Extensions.dll`, so try adding that to your references.